# Gmaps4Rails - Custom marker picture not clickable / not opening infowindow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, gmaps4rails, gmaps4rails2

I have a problem with gmaps4rails (2.1.2) when I try to use a custom `marker.picture`.

This code works perfectly:

Regular GoogleMaps Pin (red) is shown. If I click the Pin, the Infowindow opens.

```
 @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@nearbys) do |location, marker|
    marker.title location[:name]
    marker.lat location[:coordinates].y
    marker.lng location[:coordinates].x
    marker.json({title: location[:name]})
  end
```

When I add a `marker.picture` the image is shown. But it is not clickable anymore.

```
 @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@nearbys) do |location, marker|
    marker.title location[:name]
    marker.lat location[:coordinates].y
    marker.lng location[:coordinates].x
    marker.json({title: location[:name]})
    marker.picture({
                    marker_anchor: [40, 58], # added this optionally <- doesn't work either
                    url: "#{view_context.image_path("map/icons/3dmarker.png") }",
                    width: "44",
                    height: "58"
                   })
  end
```

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things:

- I doubt you have any infowindow working: you dont pass data to create it (`marker.infowindow`), so it wont be created
- replace `marker_anchor` with `anchor`
- doing `marker.title location[:name]` is the same as `marker.json({title: location[:name]})` so you have one too many

Comment: I have ```marker.infowindow render_to_string(:partial => "locations/map-infowindow", :locals => {:location => location})``` implemented. It does not work with your suggestions (change ```marker_anchor``` to ```marker``` , removing duplicated code). The infowindow is opened on start (as always). Then I close it by clicking the X. and wanna open it again by clicking on my icon. But the cursor of my mouse is not changing. I tried different values on anchor WITHOUT SUCCESS. Wiki also seems outdated: It suggests marker_anchor: https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Markers

Comment: change marker_anchor to marker ? I didnt write that

Comment: check here, having a custom pic dont change infowindow behavior: http://apneadiving.github.io/

Comment: I used your sidebar example. Placed ```marker.picture({anchor: [16, 16], :url => "#{ view_context.image_path("map/icons/categories/#{location.categories.first.slug}.png") }",:width => "32",:height => "32"})``` in my controller. And this in my view: ```var json_array = <%= raw @hash.to_json %>;var markers = handler.addMarkers(json_array); ```

Comment: whats the generated js?

Comment: It's me again! I solved it!!!! I used ```width: "32", height: "32"``` instead of ```width: 32, height: 32```. This caused the error! Thank you very, very much for your time.